# Jenkinsfile: git get change to a specific folder

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm working on a project involving a Jenkins pipeline, and I need to identify that there was a change in a specific folder within a branch in git.

I thought about using tags, in this project I have a front and an API which both go up with a docker-compose. The two halves are separated into a pair of directories, but I need to identify which one was changed to deploy.

Comment: Please provide more info to let others understand your problem and consider adding code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are checking out the repository, you can use a shell and `git`

```sh
git --oneline log ${base}..${head} -- "${path}"
```

Compare the merge base to some head or most recent commit Jenkins is aware of .. if the above command has any output, then you have a change in `$path` in `$head` which is not present in `$base`